# In android How to close dialog when a realtime message is received?

Tags: android

I have a dialogbox that comes up when a button is clicked.The code is below.

```
public void howtoplayvideo(View v){

final Dialog dialog = new    Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbox);


    Button exit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.done);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog_open=false;    //flag to know when dialog is open
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog_open=true;
    dialog.show();
}
```

When this dialog is being viewed, if a realtime message is received, then how can i close this dialog from onRealTimeMessageReceived

```
@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage rtm) {
    byte[] buf = rtm.getMessageData();
int button = (int) buf[0];
switch (button) {
        case 1:
              if(dialog_open) {
              //how to access and close dialog box here
             }
         }}
```

If I declare dialogbox public outside the method, it gives a error that cannot be initializes before onCreate.

Comment: Try putting `Dialog dialog` globally (top of your class or something) then initializing the `dialog` within your `howtoplayvideo(...)` method. I think you're initializing your `dialog` too early in the lifecycle causing that error.  This way you can keep a global instance of the `dialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dialog mDialog; 
public void howtoplayvideo(){

        mDialog = new    Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbox);


        Button exit = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.done);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mDialog.show();
    }

@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage rtm) {
    byte[] buf = rtm.getMessageData();
    int button = (int) buf[0];

     switch (button) {
        case 1:
               if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing())
                    mDialog.dismiss();
              break;
         }}
```

Make dialog as class variable, then you can use this dialog inside other method of this class.

Don't need to keep extra boolean for check weather dialog is showing or not,
Use dialog.isShowing() for this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add some explanation to your code? Code-only answers are discouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should do the trick.

There's no need to keep a boolean value of whether or not the dialog is showing. You can always use dialog.isShowing() function to check for that.

```
private Dialog dialog;

public void howtoplayvideo(View v){

    dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbox);

    Button exit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.done);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage rtm) {
    byte[] buf = rtm.getMessageData();
    int button = (int) buf[0];
    switch (button) {
        case 1:
            if(dialog != null) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare you `Dialog` Globally,and Not need for `boolean` value...you can use `isShowing()` Method like this...and dismiss the dialog..

```
@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage rtm) {
    byte[] buf = rtm.getMessageData();
int button = (int) buf[0];
switch (button) {
        case 1:
                if(dialog.isShowing()){
                         dialog.dismiss();
                     }
                    break;
             }
}
```